# what is the best method for passing information from a child to a parent object in c#

Tags: c#

I have a object that dynamically creates a number of child objects. These child objects are derived from UserControl. What is the best method to pass information to pass information back to the parent? In the past I have used the delegate event but recently I have been just using a reference to the parent in the constructer of the child objects.

I do have reservations to tight coupling as I am concerned that the child object may be tied up if the parent fails to execute the referenced  method in a timely fashion.

I didn't want to start a new question so I'll ask here.

If I have events wired for the dynamically created objects and the object is disposed of at a later time, should I be unwiring the event prior to disposing of the event.

and ... if I am keeping my dynamically created objects in an array or hashtable would simply removing that list item dispose of the item from memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will depend on the situation. Events are appropriate if one object wants to observe another and react to particular changes. Simply keeping a reference to the parent is suitable in other situations. If you want advice for a very specific case, please give details of that case.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your attitude towards tight coupling and the exact situation in hand.

Personally speaking I think that the delegate/event approach is a lot cleaner.

Passing in a reference implies that the child needs understanding of the type of the parent object? OK, you could probably use a base class or interface, but it's still required.

The upside of the delegate/event model is that the child object can just publish events and whoever is registered will receive the events. Classic observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

well, i think as Jon suggested Events are best to observe changes in other controls, this is the best.
also you can create properties in the main User control and then Get, Set it from child Controls, i do it all the time.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about tight coupling consider using an interface to the parent object, which exposes only the methods needed to pass your data back.

In order to prevent locking the child controls (resp. the UI thread) you might use a `BackgroundWorker` to do the work in a separate thread.